# How to pass commands to ADB shell?

Tags: adb, shell, command-line

I am trying to create a script to automatize a few repeated things I need to do with adb. I can run most of the commands on my local bash. But at one step, I need to find the list of some files. I then use that list in the steps that follows. What I am doing now is manually going into adb shell and copying the list:

> $ adb shell
>
> $ ls /Path/To/Folder *.abc
>
> xyz.abc  xzy.abc  uvw.abc

I copy the resulting list and replace it in my script everytime before running the script.

Is it possible to run this without going into `adb shell` so that I could do something like this:

```
$ file_list="$(adb execute 'ls /Path/To/Folder *.abc')"
```

This way I could eliminate the repetitive manual steps and just run the script every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adb interactive shell only starts if you simply run `adb shell`. If you add a command at the end it will be executed on the device shell and then adb returns (non-interactive mode):

```
adb shell ls /Path/To/Folder/*.abc
```

Of course in the end you can send the output to a `filellist.txt` on your computer:

```
adb shell ls /Path/To/Folder/*.abc > filelist.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it! Now everything I need is in the script.